# How do I make different formatting e.g., bold, italics etc to Excel files within SAS?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am trying to change formatting within an excel spreadsheet using SAS.

However, being a complete beginner to SAS, not sure how to go about it.

Googling lots made me get 'ODS Excel' and 'ODS Excel XP' as possible approaches.

'ODS Excel' is giving me corrupted files though, so I'm skipping that one.

Could someone please advise in detail on how to do something like below within each step I have written, preferably using 'ODS Excel XP'? Or if I am doing something wrong with 'ODS Excel' in my syntax, happy to use that as well.

Input file: /myfile.excel/

SAS: 
Step 1: Read myfile.excel, which looks like this

[image: below]

Step 2: Turn the title row into bold text and that whole row yellow in colour, not just the cell with the text

Step 3: Output the formatting changes to new or existing excel, I don't really care

I have no idea how to do this in SAS. Could someone help, please?

Thank you!

Update: This is my SAS version: Custom Version 9.4_M3

Comment: What version of SAS do you have? The solution is very version dependent as a lot of these are newer features in SAS. It's also why these options are not coming up in your searches, though ODS EXCEL should be the right answer, so either you're using a version too old or have been doing it wrong.

Comment: Hi @Reeza, I've updated the question with the SAS version I have

Comment: That's your EG version, not SAS. Please run the following to find your version: `proc product_status; run;`

Comment: Hi @Reeza. Thanks for that. I've updated my SAS version.

Comment: It needs to be the full version ie 9.4 TS1M5. The M portion is important because ODS EXCEL is only in production as of M3 and stable, IMO, as of M5. Otherwise you're stuck with ODS TAGSETS but it doesn't generate a native XLSX file.

Comment: Hi @Reeza, thanks for that. I've updated the question again, It's M3

Comment: I'm assuming you have an answer based on you posting it. ODS EXCEL ended up working? Search for a paper call ringside seat ODS EXCEL and it has a lot of examples.